# UserControl loading slow at startup

Tags: c#, user-controls

I have an XML list of data that is used to create my usercontrol. My usercontrol itself uses a **third-party** library that creates network instances for each xml data unit (it's about 120 now).
Now everything works fine but it takes about 30 seconds to display the usercontrols in my main form and it displays only after ALL usercontrols have been created.
I've been away from C# for quite some time and have missed the Task ,  async and await additions. But there are so many ways to change it and I need some pointers to help.

Comment: what does debugging it show takes the long time?

Comment: You might want to try searching for "c# unblock ui thread"